# How do I extract some values from a file?

Tags: regex, file, extract

I have been setting up openHAB home automation and I want to display some figures from an energy monitor. I can get data displayed from the built in web server with http://ipaddres/ecostatus.json but then I have to extract some values from the returned data. The first few lines of the returned data are;

[{"CHANNEL":"CH1A",
"NAME":"Mains",
"WATT":0.000,
"NWATT":2540.969,
"COST":0.000,
"VOL":242,
"ALERT":0,

I want to get the string after "WATT": up to the decimal point in line 3.
Next I want to get the string value after "NWATT": up to the decimal point in line 4.
The string "Mains","WATT": is unique in the file so that isn't too bad as far as I can see but because the string after "WATT": can vary in length I'm not sure how to get the value of NWATT.
As this is my first attempt at using regex any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's JSON format so you would be better of using a JSON parser. Once parsed you will be able to access the properties directly.

your JSON is composed of an array, so you need to iterate to the first item of the array to get the objet you want.

```
const channel = JSON.parse('[{ "CHANNEL":"CHA1A"...}]');
channel[0].NAWATT //should be 2540.969
```

Next time you ask a question you would get better answers if you specify the programming language you are using

Comment: Thanks fred.I'm using openHAB. In openHAB I can read an HTML message and extract data because of an HTML Binding and Regex Transformation (addons). This is an example for something similar that someone has given in another topic on the openHAB Community forum.   String Http_Meteoalarm_TodayTest "MeteoAlarm [%s]" { http="<[https://www.meteoalarm.eu/en_UK/0/0/AT008-Burgenland.html/:5000:REGEX(.*aw.*?([0-9]+[0-9]+).*.?)]"}   While questions like this are asked in that forum I thought I would ask where more people are experienced in regex.

Comment: If you can find a json parser it will be much easier, you may google for it I found that as first google result

https://community.openhab.org/t/solved-how-to-parse-a-json-string-into-different-oh-items/35368